# Openshot Help saving

Tags: helpfile

I’m a open shot beginner, I need help saving my open shot files to something i can use to upload to you tube (I didn’t know if that made sense) like mp4 or mpg. When I Try And put the .osp and upload it to one my channel ( you tube )
But it wouldn't support the file!

Answer (score 1):

You should choose the Export video option from File, and then you can either select as Profil Web and then the next combo YouTube, or you can select All formats and then MP4(h.264). Let me know, if you need screenshots...